# Does Avenue equivalent of pointPosition exist in ArcGIS 10.2?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, geometry

There were a couple of awesome methods in Avenue for ArcView:

```
point=polyline.Along(percentage)
percentage=polyLine.pointPosition(point)
```

Don't laugh, but one of the reasons I updated to 10 from 9, was new method for Geometry

```
point=polyline.positionAlongLine (value,{use_percentage})
```

that is equivalent of 1st Avenue method (wrong name in my opinion anyway).

Does an equivalent of the 2nd Avenue method exist in ArcPy with ArcMap 10.2?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it does exist. Use [`polyline.measureOnLine(point_geometry)`](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018z00000070000000).

> measureOnLine (in_point, {as_percentage})
>
> Returns a measure from the start point of this line to the in_point.